# Communicating to Docker container on OSX

Tags: docker, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to run some ROS-related things natively on OSX (simulators to take advantage of GPU acceleration), and the majority of the rest of a ROS system in an Ubuntu Docker container (to take advantage of packages and standards). Is this possible? If so, does anyone have an example of the configuration required?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271461/communicating-to-docker-container-on-osx/) by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 282 on 2017-09-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the Docker for Mac install has a special network config, as it really just hosts a lightweight VM for the linux kernel. That config kind of makes it tricky to expose ROS containers transparently. I don't think it's impossible, but I haven't seen a properly solved issue on it posted on answers.ros yet, and I don't own a mac to debug it. My guess is if you could just get to the point in being able to address the VM on Mac via a unique IP, then load containers onto the host via docker run --net=host, then all ports would be easily accessible, and all you'd need to do is just keep in mind the ROS master URI.

Related:
https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues/55
https://answers.ros.org/question/269335/adding-gui-to-docker-on-osx/

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2017-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0